# PHP date entering as 1970

Tags: php, mysql, validation, date

Hi I am trying to fix an old piece of code created by another developer. Spent a while fixing it to work with mysqli. Anyway the last thing on my list is to fix the dates error.
there is no actual error but if you submit the form with a valid date on it always shows up in the table as `01-01-1970`
Below is the piece of code which is formatting the date. The date enters this in the format `DD-MM-YY`.

```
$arr[$i] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($date) );
```

The result so far is always `01-01-1970`

here are some of y attempts at fixing it all with the same output:

```
$arr[$i] = $date;
```

```
$arr[$i] = strtotime($date);
```

and many variations of the `strftime` settings!

Comment: Try using DateTime objects and [createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: Can you provide us with a `var_dump($date)`?

Comment: @Kieranmv95 if you're trying to insert the current date(as in today's date) you can simple using **`NOW()`** in the MySQL query and it will take care of it for you, if its a future or past date then you will have to format it for MySQL which takes it as `YEAR-MONTH-DAY` for example `2015-01-12`.

Comment: It can take previous days I not always `now()` (I wish it was). I am now going to try the dump and I have checked the DB its definatly a DATETIME format field

Comment: @Dencker it is returning `null` so I am going t try and find the piece of code which "should" assign it the date

Comment: @Kieranmv95 that's the problem. `strtotime` will return 0, which `date()` or the equivalent interprets as a unix timestamp meaning "0 seconds after 01-01-1970". Good idea to trace it backwards to the code that assigns the date variable. You're on the right track.

Comment: Fixed using the `var_dump()` to find the issue. Thanks a lot I don't know how I didn't think of this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you considered using date()?

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

so...

```
$arr[$i] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($date) );
```

becomes

```
 $arr[$i] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date) );
```

Comment: same problem with this

Comment: can you try a var_dump($arr[$i]) and see what it is? Also check the field type of your column, it should be a DateTime if you are using MySql

Answer (score 0):

Try using DateTime objects and [createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), so you can explicitly define the format of your `$date` value

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y',$date);
$arr[$i] = $dt->format("Y-m-d");
```